# A VBS script that edits a shortcut while setting a default homepage

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

My script

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Internet Explorer.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" & "www.google.com"
shortcut.Save
```

However this doesn't work when I run it, rather it creates a .PIF with the target being 
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exewww.google.com"

I've tried it with double quotes but that didn't work.

Now I do add a space and it does the same thing. I'm starting to think that what I'm after isn't possible in script. Any help would be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string concatenation in your code creates the following string:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exewww.google.com
```

Since the extension `.com` indicates an 8-bit DOS binary a `.pif` shortcut is created instead of a `.lnk` shortcut.

You need to specify arguments to the executable via the `Arguments` property to make the shortcut turn out the way you want:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\owner\Desktop\Internet Explorer.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
shortcut.Arguments  = "www.google.com"
shortcut.Save
```